# Definition brownian motion: what does $W_t$ almost surely mean?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion, it says that for a Brownian motion $\{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, we have that $W_t$ is almost surely continuous. What exactly does this mean?

Does this mean that

$$\mathbb{P}(\omega\in \Omega: t \mapsto W_t(\omega) \mathrm{\ is \ continuous})= 1$$? Or is there another interpretation?

Comment: It is a common practice to assume that $t \to W_t(\omega)$ is continuous for every $\omega$.

Comment: Yes, but this does not quite answer my question. I want to understand what the above means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what they are saying is there is a set $E$ of probability $0$ such that $\omega \notin E$ implies $t \to W_t(\omega)$ is continuous. Measurability of $\{\omega: t \to W_t(\omega) \text{  is continuous} \}$ is not assumed. What you have written is correct if the probability space is assumed to be complete.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about the measurability problem! Very good point.